# validates_presence _of with non standard forgien key

Tags: ruby-on-rails, validation

I'm making a very small rails app for another group in my company and their specifications require non rails conventions in a few places. What I'm having problems with is validating the value of a fkey field using the validates_presence_of. No matter what value I give it, the validation fails. Here is my setup

```
# migration approver_types
t.integer :query_type, index: true, null: false

# migration approval_query_types
t.integer :enum, index:true, null: false

# model approver_type
belongs_to :approval_query_type, foreign_key: 'enum'
validates_presence_of :approval_query_type
```

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 0):

If you are on Rails 4+, try adding `required: true` to the `belongs_to` options and removing the presence validation:

`belongs_to :approval_query_type, foreign_key: 'enum', required: true`

Comment: sorry I should have mentioned i tried that as well, same reuslts, always fails validation

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you use `enum` field as primary key in `ApprovalQueryType` (but index is not unique, as it should in this case)

Rails by default expects it to be `id`, and validation will (almost) always fail.
If so, try adding

```
self.primay_key = 'enum'
```

to second model (+unique index and auto increment probably)

Comment: enum is not the primary key on the table, it has a normal id field but they just want the fkey to go to enum for whatever reason. I do have a uniqueness validator for enum in the model just no index for it.